# Is there a VB6 function like mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: vb6

Is there a function in VB6 analagous to `mysql_real_escape_string` I can use to escape strings for an access database, to prevent things like newlines and double quotes from wrecking the insert statements?

The strings concerned are hard-coded in the application so SQL injection is not a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Fraid not, you can either use `Replace$()` to escape quotes yourself, or take advantage of the ADODB Command object's ability to create use [parameterized statements](http://msaccess-dox.net/MS.Press-Programming.Microsoft1/8368final/LiB0014.html) which will escape any character data automatically.

Comment: Thank you, Alex K. I've gone with the Replace option.

Comment: Careful, there are far more things you need to escape than quotes!  SQL injection concerns or not... you don't want to open your queries up to failure because you missed something.